# .htaccess dash in argument

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx, mod-rewrite

I have the following htaccess rule:

```
RewriteRule ^listen/([^/]*)-([^/]*)/$ listen.php?pl=$1&id=$2
```

Sometimes the second argument (id) has a dash in it and I get 404 Not found, e.g:

`mysite.com/listen/something-293Xff4-yZ`
( the ID is `293Xff4-yZ`)

The issue is that when I'm trying to get the ID argument (using `$_GET['id']`) - I get only the first part of the ID (before the dash - `293Xff4`)

Any idea how I can getthe full part of the ID in this case?

Thanks!

Comment: What are examples of URLs causing 404 errors?

Comment: @anubhava Added an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex in `RewriteRule`:

```
RewriteRule ^listen/([^-]+)-([^/]+)/?$ listen.php?pl=$1&id=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

It is also recommended to use `Options -MultiView` at top of your .htaccess as it may cause problems on some Apache versions where it is enabled by default.

Comment: Still, `$_GET['id']` returns the first part before the dash, missing the `yZ`

Comment: Ah I had a mistake, can you please try my updated rule now.

Comment: `[^-]+` will return part before first `-` after `/listen/` and `[^/]+` will match everything before next `/`